# VBA fill Two Dimensional with array function

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to fill a two dimensional array with static values using the Array function

I know I can do the following for a single dimensional array

```
dim vOneDimArray as variant
vOneDimArray=Array("A","B","C")
```

I discovered that I can do the followiong

```
Dim vTwoDArray as variant
vTwoDArray = Array(Array("A","z"),Array("B","y"),Array("C","x"))
```

However in order to access the data you have use

```
Debug.print vTwoDArray(0)(0)  ' prints "A"
```

Trying

```
Debug.Print vTwoDArray(0,0)  ' give subscript error, I don't know why
```

How do I do the same type of thing for a two dimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

You can't that simple way. Dim an array variable:

```
Dim MyArray(x, n) As String
```

Then run a loop (inside another loop for each dimension) that fills the elements with your values.